# How to root ZTE Z223?

Tags: rooting

The title says it all. Here's a link to the about page on the AT&T website.
https://www.att.com/cellphones/att/z223-prepaid.html#sku=sku7920249

The phone doesn't have an android-esque interface, however, I was able to identify this after looking through the device driver files.

Comment: What makes you think this is an Android device... I would be frankly shocked if it was based on Android at all. These feature phones do not have sufficient storage or RAM to run Android in such a limited interface. OEMs are not going to go through the work do develop this for less than $20 a phone.

Comment: Android devices are either required to have navigation keys (at least Back and Home) on screen or on the keypad. This device has neither.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a non-Android phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't root that. It's a flip phone that DOES NOT RUN ANDROID! I know this is an extremely short answer, but there's no other way to explain it.